# Select tabItem programmatically when selecting an element in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, tabitem

I have an image editor which has a number of image elements and text elements on a canvas. I have two separate tabs which allow the user to re-size the text or image. I'd like to switch to the text tab when I select a text element and switch to the image tab when I select an image. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

MainPage.xaml -

```
<!-- Control Panel -->
<sdk:TabControl x:Name="elementEditor" Margin="10,0,10,19" Width="215" Background="#FFD6D6D6"
       Grid.RowSpan="2">//removed selectedIndex binding from here
<sdk:TabItem x:Name="tabCanvasSettings" DataContext="{Binding Project}">
    <sdk:TabItem.Header x:Name="tabCanvas">
        <TextBlock Text="Canvas" />
    </sdk:TabItem.Header>
    <sdk:TabItem.Content>
        <!-- Content -->
    </sdk:TabItem.Content>
</sdk:TabItem>

<!-- Text tab -->
<sdk:TabItem x:Name="tabText" IsSelected="{Binding Path=TabTextSel}">
    <sdk:TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Text" />
    </sdk:TabItem.Header>
    <sdk:TabItem.Content>
        <!-- Content -->
    </sdk:TabItem.Content>
</sdk:TabItem>

<!-- Image tab -->
<sdk:TabItem x:Name="tabImage" IsSelected="{Binding Path=TabImgSel}">
    <sdk:TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Image" />
    </sdk:TabItem.Header>
    <sdk:TabItem.Content>
        <!-- Content -->
    </sdk:TabItem.Content>
</sdk:TabItem>
</sdk:TabControl>
```

Project.cs (not my MainPage code-behind) -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using ImageEditor.Client.Behaviors;
using ImageEditor.Client.Views;
using System.Linq;
using ImageEditor.Client.ImageDesignerService;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace ImageEditor.Client.BLL
{
  public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private bool tabTextSel;
    public bool TabTextSel
    {
        get { return tabTextSel; }
        set
        {
            tabTextSel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TabTextSel");
        }
    }

    private bool tabImgSel;
    public bool TabImgSel
    {
        get { return tabImgSel; }
        set
        {
            tabImgSel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TabImgSel");
        }
    }
    //Other properties and methods

    public void element_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (sender is TextBlock)
        {
            this.SelectedTextElement = sender as TextBlock;

            //Change tab to text tab
            tabImgSel = false;
            tabTextSel = true;
        }
        else if (sender is Image)
        {
            this.SelectedImageElement = sender as Image;

            //Change tab to image tab
            tabTextSel = false;
            tabImgSel = true;
        }

    }

  }
}
```

How do I get it to switch tabs here? I'm sure it's probably something simple, I just can't put my finger on it.  The values seem to be passed to the bindings just fine when I debug but they still aren't switching right

Comment: any final solution  with full source code?

Answer (score 1):

Your properties (TabTextSel and TabImgSel) should be of type bool, not string. And you should set them to true of false (bool).

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely one simple thing. I've updated my code above accordingly. It still isn't switching tabs however. When debugging, it seems to work fine. The bindings are showing the correct values of true and false but the tabs aren't switching

Comment: @Steve You need to change your binding paths from Project.TabImgSel to TabImgSel etc. You don't need to specify "Project" inside a binding path, because you already set it to DataContext.

Comment: Oh, I had actually changed that already but forgot to update the code I used in the question. So it still isn't switching with that changed

Comment: So, I set IsSelected ="true" explicitly, and this causes it to be set to the selected tab when I run the application. So IsSelected="true" works. That's not the problem, obviously. With my bound values - When I debug I can see that tabTextSel and tabImgSel are being set correctly when I click the element. If I hover over the bindings on my MainPage.xaml for IsSelected, the binding values are shown as true or false correctly, but it still isn't switching...???

Comment: @Steve you should put your DataContext to the TabControl, or some parent control, not the first TabItem. Make sure your DataContext is set correctly.

Comment: The DataContext is set in a parent control. I feel that it's not a binding problem as when I put a watch on the bound values in the XAML when debugging they are changed correctly but nothing happens

Comment: I don't know if I can help you any further, but this line is very suspicious to me: <sdk:TabItem x:Name="tabCanvasSettings" DataContext="{Binding Project}">

Comment: @Steve Try to add Mode=TwoWay to your IsSelected bindings.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I moved off of it for a while. Changing my mode to TwoWay had no effect. I'll double check my bindings, though I feel like they're working ok as debugging seems to suggest the values are ok. It's one of those things where I feel I'm very close to the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign to the property not the variable so the databinding can work by calling your NotifyPropertyChanged method....